# Custom component not visible - SWING

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I am making a custom JComponent to my Swing GUI.

```
public class BreadCrump extends JComponent implements MouseListener,
    MouseMotionListener{
JPanel cajaPrincipal;
JLabel nombre;
JLabel propiedadUsada;
JLabel numeroApariciones; //OPCIONAL

public BreadCrump(String nombre, String relacion)
{

}

public BreadCrump(String nombre)
{
    this.nombre = new JLabel(nombre);
    this.cajaPrincipal = new JPanel();
    this.cajaPrincipal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,40));
    this.cajaPrincipal.setSize(60, 40);
    this.cajaPrincipal.add(this.nombre);
    this.cajaPrincipal.setBackground(Color.blue);
    this.nombre.setLocation(10, 10);
    this.cajaPrincipal.setVisible(true);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,40));
    this.setSize(60,40);
    this.setBackground(Color.red);
    this.setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
addMouseMotionListener(this);

}
```

And create the objects in this fragment of code:

```
JPanel a = new JPanel();
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(a);
    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
//sp.setBounds(0, 0,father.getSize().width, height);

this.add(sp);
father.add(this, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    BreadCrump prueba = new BreadCrump("prueba " + i);
    a.add(prueba);
}
```

The problem is that I cant see the component. The component exists an is inside my JPanel 'a' and the JScrollPane detect it because the scroll bar appears.

I tried to change JComponent to JPanel and it works, i can see the JPanel(when I change the color and the preferredSize). But I dont know why can not see my JComponent.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Maybe I need put a location to the component? I tried to add size and visible but nothing occurs.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry but your code give me no hints about what's wrong. But as I see, you have added no components to your `BreadCrump`.

Comment: Yes Sergiy, thats my mistake. I need to add this.add(cajaPrincipal) and all is ok. Thanks!!